# No Route Found for Images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am little bit confuse that I am showing images through css it's working fine. But when I am showing images using views it's not display. Following is simple code I am using. But I cannot find what's wrong!

new.html.erb

```
<h1>Users#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
<img src='close.png'>
```

I am getting this error in console:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/close.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
```

This is the dir image of project:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use the [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper method - this will put in the right src path for you automatically, so long as you are storing your images where the asset pipeline expects them to be (you are). e.g.

```
<%= image_tag 'close.png' %>
```