# Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed Omniauth Facebook

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I am getting error in rails - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed. I am trying [RailsCast Omniauth Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth). It's working fine with Twitter. But when I give

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook
```

it's giving error. I have also see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed), but problem not solved.

Settings on developer.facebook.com

```
Site URL: http://localhost:3000/
Site Domain: localhost
```

I am using windows. I have also read [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed).

Thanks!

Comment: That's good! But I don't know what to do.

Comment: You mean I have to add this question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: No, I am not talking at all about your current question. I am talking about how you should use Stack Overflow. When you ask a question here and someone provides an answer to it which solves your problem (as here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10964592/29407) you have to accept this answer instead of just saying *Oh great! It's working. Thank you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. This problem might be for windows users only. Use this,

[1](https://raw.github.com/gist/867550/win_fetch_cacerts.rb) Save this file on your desktop [win_fetch_cacerts.rb](https://raw.github.com/gist/867550/win_fetch_cacerts.rb)

[2](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) Use this command on command prompt

```
ruby "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\win_fetch_cacerts.rb"
```

[3] Save this [file](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) on your c:\RailsInstaller\

[4] On your command prompt or set as environment variable

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
```

[5] Restart your system and try.