# Rails Facebook Omniauth Faraday Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I have a OS X 10.8.2 with ruby-1.9.3-p374 and rails 3.2.11.
I have followed the #360 Facebook Authentication guide on rails cast but when i try to sign in i receive the error:

```
Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

How can i resolve this problem? There is any clear guide?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already few similar questions about this, I suggest you to take a look and see if those solutions works for you.

- [Omniauth Facebook Error - Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775640/omniauth-facebook-error-faradayerrorconnectionfailed)
- [OmniAuth & Facebook: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977303/omniauth-facebook-certificate-verify-failed)
- [Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed Omniauth Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028216/faradayerrorconnectionfailed-omniauth-facebook) (Windows only)